# On startup of database it denies with error ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters | LRM-00109: could not open parameter file?

Tags: oracle

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 9 15:06:37 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn sys@Databasename as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> shutdown abort;
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup nomount;
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\VIRTUAL\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITdatabasename.ORA'
SQL>
```

If I go to `C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\VIRTUAL\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\` There is no file with this name `INITdatabasename.ORA`

After search I found that I should create a `pfile` from `spfile`.

```
SQL> create pfile from spfile;
create pfile from spfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file '?=\DATABASE\SPFILE%ORACLE_SID%.ORA'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.
```

`SPfile` is available in database folder. But is unable to open. Please help.

Comment: Never do `shutdown abort`, it basically kills the RDBMS process while some of files (data files or configure files) are being written into. After an abort you will have to recover your database, so if you don't have automatic REDO log configured or you don't have backups, then you're in trouble. Do `shutdown immediate`

Comment: I will take care.SQL> shutdown immediate;
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Comment: Have you set ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME env variables in console before to start sqlplus?

Comment: Yes i set Oracle_SID and Oracle_Home. I verified too through echo %Oracle_SID% and echo %Oracle_home%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify spfile and pfile locations:

```
create pfile='path_to_pfile' from spfile='path_to_spfile';
```

Comment: Same error as mentioned in question even with path.

Comment: CREATE PFILE = 'Path\INITDB.ORA' FROM SPFILE = 'Path\SPFILEDB.ORA'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file
'Path\SPFILEDB.ORA
'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.

Comment: Are you sure that the user on which oracle is running have permissions to those files?

Comment: Path? You need to specify full path, not relative

Comment: I used the full path.

Comment: @GeographyUp have you checked file permissions? 'Path\SPFILEDB.ORA' - doesn't look like full path

Comment: And anyway you can always create minimum pfile and start database using it: `startup pfile=c:\temp\new_pfile.ora`  Simple example: https://gist.github.com/xtender/7ad497f99ad89c78bb9796e427be25d5

Comment: Thank you Sayan. Full query looks like CREATE PFILE = 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\VIRTUAL\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITCOVID19.ORA' FROM SPFILE = 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\VIRTUAL\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILECOVID19.ORA';
Result is the same as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: You need to check oracle service login account in Windows services and spfile file permissions. Have you configured oracle to run as system or virtual account?

Comment: I created a initdatabasename.ora file in Database folder from other RDBMS and changed the required information such as db name, control files and db version etc. I startedup the database. And results in next comment;

Comment: SQL> conn sys@covid19 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> Startup nomount PFILE = 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\VIRTUAL\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITCOVID19.ORA';
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1073741824 bytes
Fixed Size                  8755072 bytes
Variable Size             713033856 bytes
Database Buffers          343932928 bytes
Redo Buffers                8019968 bytes

Comment: SQL> alter database mount;
alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info


SQL> Select name,open_mode from v$database;
Select name,open_mode from v$database
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01507: database not mounted

Comment: SQL> select name,value,ISDEFAULT,ISSES_MODIFIABLE,ISSYS_MODIFIABLE from v$parameter where name='processes';

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISDEFAULT ISSES ISSYS_MOD
--------- ----- ---------
processes
150
FALSE     FALSE FALSE


SQL>

Comment: I configured oracle to a virtual machine.

Comment: Ok, so original problem had been resolved, now you have another problem and it's better to create appropriate new topic. It's not convenient to answer on comments

Comment: Thank you, Sayan for your efforts. I am going to install a new database i think i would safe time. And import available dmp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to restore it from backups if you have any.
Bellow you have a good guide:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/11/oracle-rman-restore/